# Careful. You almost hit the cabinet

Tags: grammar

He didn't look where he was going and almost hit the cabinet.

> "Careful. You almost hit the cabinet."
>
> "Careful. You are about to hit the cabinet."
>
> "Careful. You nearly hit the cabinet."

Almost, about and nearly. Which one is suitable in the context above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and third examples would work based upon the context that you have given me.  The second example would be correct if he were about to hit the cabinet, but he had not hit it yet.